# Postgres - Update permissions on tables have no effect

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions

User: jira_user Database: jiradb
As postgres executing commands

```
GRANT USAGE ON schema public TO jira_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO jira_user;
grant all privileges on database jiradb to jira_user;
```

But even so, I get the following result when on the test server

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_privileges where table_name = 'AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE';
 grantor  |  grantee  | table_catalog | table_schema |        table_name         | privilege_type | is_grantable | with_hierarchy 
----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | INSERT         | NO           | NO
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | SELECT         | NO           | YES
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | UPDATE         | NO           | NO
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | DELETE         | NO           | NO
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | TRUNCATE       | NO           | NO
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | REFERENCES     | NO           | NO
 postgres | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | TRIGGER        | NO           | NO
```

From the prod server - it should look like this

```
  grantor  |  grantee  | table_catalog | table_schema |        table_name         | privilege_type | is_grantable | with_hierarchy 
-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------+----------------
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | INSERT         | YES          | NO
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | SELECT         | YES          | YES
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | UPDATE         | YES          | NO
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | DELETE         | YES          | NO
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | TRUNCATE       | YES          | NO
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | REFERENCES     | YES          | NO
 jira_user | jira_user | jiradb        | public       | AO_013613_ACTIVITY_SOURCE | TRIGGER        | YES          | NO`
```

Must admit that I'm not all into Postgres, but I would expect the grant commands to fix this and then also provide the same output in test as in prod. Now realizing that the first column is showing diffrently "grantor". Not sure if this is important.

Comment: I did run the grants, but it has no effect. But maybe I am not fully understanding the column is_grantable. Is to be understood as "Granted / Not granted" or when reading it maybe it is "Possible to grant / Not possible to grant" meaning I need to do some magic "on a higher level" to make it grantable?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that on the "prod server" the permissions have been granted `WITH GRANT OPTION`, so that `jira_user` can grant them to other users. That would be done like this:

```
RANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
   TO jira_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You should *never* grant the `TRIGGER` privilege. It is a security leak, as it allows the user to execute arbitrary code with your permissions.